# How to navigate from child tab to parent tab in native base tabs?

Tags: react-native, native-base

The scenario is like I have a native base tab, where I have 4 tabs. In the second tab, I have a children tab, which has 4 more tabs. What I need is I need to navigate to the parent tab's first tab, when the button is clicked on any of the children's tabs. I just tried to navigate using `this.props.navigation.navigate('tab')`, but it wasn't successful. Can anyone suggest some way to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create stack with 4 tab child. create bottomTabbar with 4 tab parent. and nest stack to bottomTab.

For example stack

```
export const AssignStack = createStackNavigator({
Assign,
Search,
SearchResults,
TaskList,
TaskElement,
TaskDetail,
}
```

For example BottomTab

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
Mine: MineStack,
Assign: AssignStack,
Related: RelatedStack,
Chatting: ChatStack,
Notify: Notify,
Setting: SettingStack
}
```

In your stack, You can use this.props.navigation.navigate('MineStack').
Sorry for the presentation and my English not good. Hope help you

Comment: Hi @Trịnh Đức Duy, can you please elaborate a little. Like, I have two child tabs in `Assign`. From there if I need to move to `Mine`, I can simply use `this.props.navigation.navigate('Mine')` right? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: https://github.com/Duya3fithou/DemoNavigation4x
Here is example i made for you. @Sriram

Comment: You can use `this.props.navigation.navigate('MineStack')` not `this.props.navigation.navigate('Mine')`.  But not recommended. You shoud use "reset" instead of "navigate"

Comment: Thank you for the sample repo mate :-) @Trịnh Đức Duy
_reset_ method worked well for me.